# Can't connect to mongolab through flask pymongo on heroku

Tags: python, heroku, flask, pymongo, mlab

The code below works on localhost. I get the message '50' which is the number of rows I have. But it doesn't work when I push it to heroku. I get the "Application error message" and the heroku logs just say app crashed.

And yes, the heroku app has the mongolab add-on connected.

What am I doing incorrectly?

```
import os
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.pymongo import PyMongo

app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True

app.config['MONGO_URI'] = os.environ['MONGOLAB_URI']
mongo = PyMongo(app, config_prefix='MONGO')

@app.route("/")
def hello():
  num = mongo.db.test.count()
  return '%s' % num

if __name__ == "__main__":
  app.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

On heroku (unless you've changed it) mongolab stores its URI at `MONGOLAB_URI` (per [these](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/mongolab) docs).

The crash is probably PyMongo saying it can't connect to NULL, but you can check that with `heroku logs` on the cli.

Comment: It's still not working even after using the environment variable

Comment: Are you sure your local pymongo version is the same as the one you're loading on heroku? your code looks really different from this; https://api.mongodb.org/python/current/tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

Check that you PyMongo version is compatible with Mongo 3.0. MongoLab has switched to it recently: http://blog.mongolab.com/2015/07/mongodb-version-3-0-now-ga-on-mongolab/